# How to completely disable password saving in Safari?

Tags: safari

Safari keeps asking if I want to save passwords whenever I submit a login form.

Is there any way to disable this password saving feature completely?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If AutoFill is disabled, Safari won't ask to save passwords either.

[image]